# PHP RegEx: "Either One Period Sign, Or At Least One Dash"

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble formulating this simple thing via regex, and would appreciate a bit of advice.

This tiny pattern says, "either one period sign, or one dash":

```
[.-]
```

What I'm looking for is the pattern that would say instead, "either one period sign, or **one or more** dashes".

How can that be expressed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just break them apart, using a pipe:

```
[.]|-+
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rohit Jain - should I place them inside the parentheses, like so ([.]|-+) ?

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. But it's not needed.'

Comment: Thanks again, @Rohit Jain -- and also – are the square brackets needed in this case for the period sign [.] or should I just escape it instead: \. ?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov. Yeah you can escape it too. Basically since you know it's a meta-character, so you have two ways to make it just a period. one escaping, and other character class.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, @Rohit Jain, I've learned something valuable from you!

Comment: why not just `\.|-+`? using `[]` to match a single char is redundant.

Comment: @MarcB. Yeah sure it may be redundant, but it's all ones choice. I prefer to use character class rather than escaping all the meta-characters, that makes it confusing to read regex TO ME. So, it's just a CHOICe.